# How to insert an image and a table together in one page in landscape mode?

Tags: rotating

I would like to insert an image and a table in landscape within a chapter in report class. Here is a sample code that I have used:

```
\begin{landscape}

    \input{./Ch3/Tables/t01_innov_eq.tex}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    % \centering
    % \includegraphics[width=19.7cm]{fig01_G1_bi_Sa_T_H7p1_W19p7.eps}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=19.7cm]{fig01_G1_bi_Sa_T_H7p1_W19p7.eps}
        \caption{RS: (a) SA, and (b) SD.}
        \label{fig:fig01_G1_bi_Sa_T3}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
```

The issue with this code is that it creates a discontinuous page. However, if I use `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable`, it puts both the table and image on different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table and the figure into the same `sideways...` environment. In the following example, I have used `sidewaystable` and `\caption{figure}{...}` for the figure's caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{sidewaystable}
   \caption{table caption}
   \label{table}
   \begin{tabular}{l}
      tabular contents here
   \end{tabular}

   \includegraphics[width=19.7cm]{example-image}
   \captionof{figure}{RS: (a) SA, and (b) SD.}
   \label{fig:fig01_G1_bi_Sa_T3}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!